# Use of globalization & localization in a multi-layer .net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, globalization

I have created a multi-language and multi-layer .net core project. I have used globalization & localization to make multilingual Project. Data Layer,Resources and web Project are seperate from each other.I know how to implement globalization when the resource folder is in the main layer.

Startup:

```
services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
            services.AddLocalization();
            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(
                options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                    {
                        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                        return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                    };
                       
                });
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opt =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("fa"),
                        new CultureInfo("en")
                    };

                    opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("fa");
                    opt.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    opt.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

I created the files in the resource layer and in the resource folder for example for Layout in the shared folder as follows:
_Layout.en-US.resx  and
_Layout.fa-IR.resx

but when I run project, Resources are not known in Layout. How can I use resources for Models and views in another layers?

Comment: Do you meet any error message? Whether these resx files are in the resource folder or not? Here is a sample about [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you could check it. From this article and the sample code, it seems that the IViewLocalizer service provides localized strings for a view, please check your view page code, make sure it also contains the similar service.

Comment: I don't have an error. In the one-layer project, I have no problem using globalization, but in a multi-layer project it doesn't work for me. in layout in main layer,  for example, when I use @localizar["Home"], It doesn't show the value I saved in the resource file and shows the key that is Home.